# aspell, contractions, and curved-quotes

Tags: emacs, aspell

In recent emacs, there is the possibility to turn on `electric-quote-mode`; see e.g. [the manual, here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Quotation-Marks.html).

And then e.g. ordinary single-quotes ' are automatically replaced with curved-quotes ’ as one types them.

But aspell compains about contractions formed with these curved-quotes:  e.g.  in emacs, flyspell flags

wouldn’t

as a possible mis-spelling, but not

wouldn't.

This [3-year-old blog post](http://endlessparentheses.com/ispell-and-apostrophes.html) proposes a solution, and while I follow what it is doing, part of me hopes (!?!!) that it is unnecessarily complex.

I'm a bit confused why I don't find more discussion of this by searching online ...

Is there a known "best way" to approach this matter?

Thanks!
-george

Comment: Sounds like a bug (?). Maybe `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Drew: thanks for the suggestion, which I will do. I had held off e.g. because the problem seems identical to that described in the 3-year-old blog post cited in my original posting. Also: it is perhaps more of an aspell bug (?) than an emacs bug (??).